# Why is one of the terms ignored when finding the variance of a sample of 5 sales?

Tags: statistics

$2,4,5,2,7$

Mean: $4$

Variance: $\large\frac{4+0+1+4+9}{5}=\frac{18}{5}$

Standard deviation: $\large\sqrt{\frac{18}{5}}=1.90$

The answer ignores the $(4-4)^2$, so that is $\large\sqrt{\frac{4+1+4+9}{4}}=2.12$,
why?

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this is on hold so I cannot answer even though the question seems clear now.  The zero is not skipped.  When you measure the STATISTIC (from a stochastic sample, as the question says), you divide by n-1 for the stat. variance.  You would use N only for the parametric version (if you had access to every possible selling day in history).

Comment: ...where N is the population size (every date in history where sales were made; generally impossible to get in a case like this hence the need for statistics) and n is the sample size (here 5 but again you remove a degree of freedom with a minus one).  I'd explain why if the question were still open.

Comment: ...but the short version: think about it like this. If I gave you the mean of five numbers, and also four of those numbers, you could calculate the fifth. Only four of five numbers are free to vary if you include the mean in your equation. This causes you to underpredict what the true parameter is likely to be (in this case you are using sample variance statistic to predict population variance parameter). Subtracting one degree of freedom from sample size fixes estimate. Get it? :)

Comment: @TrixieWolf: The question is open now.

Comment: @JonasMeyer Thanks for the note!  I think I exhausted my info here a long while back, though.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always possible that an error was made. A more likely explanation is that they are computing the "unbiased" estimator for the variance, where we divide by $N-1$ instead of $N$. Please see the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Uncorrected_sample_standard_deviation) for a discussion.

There are reasonable arguments for each of $\frac{1}{N}\sum_1^N (x_i -\bar{x})^2$ and $\frac{1}{N-1}\sum_1^N (x_i -\bar{x})^2$. I suggest checking what version is used in the "official" material for your course.

Comment: The question said a sample so the sample variance is indicated, which means one degree of freedom should be removed.  See my comments to OP's question.

Comment: It is a little more complicated, because though the estimator with the $N-1$ is unbiased, the one with the $N$ is for many distributions on average closer to the truth.

Answer (score 1):

A common question.  Another way to say this:  To compute the variance of the sample, you divide by $5$.  But is that what you are interested in?  Is this a random sample of some large population?  Are you not interested in estimating the variance of that  population?  If so, divide by $4$.

Beginners may be confused by this.  An unbiased estimate for the mean of the population is the mean of the random sample.  But for the variance, be careful.  The variance of the sample is **not** an unbiased estimate of the variance of the population.